# using i686-w64-mingw32-g++ for static libraries

Tags: static, java-native-interface

I have a JNI project, which I have to make work on Windows (I am working on Linux). This project actually depends on third-party library file which is static (archived i.e .a files). I am trying to create a JNI shared library file using  `i686-w64-mingw32-g++` and including `-static` followed by static third-party library name. Following is the command I am using

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -v -L./ -L/home/user/jre1.8.0_40/lib/amd64/ -I/user/all/apps/Linux2/x86_64/gcc/4.8.2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/include -shared  -o test.dll test.cpp  -lstdc++ -static -thirdparty
```

In-spite of placing the third party library in the current working directory, I keep getting error

```
/user/all/apps/Linux2/src/mxe/2013_12_03/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -thirdparty
```

Please note : I included `-I/user/all/apps/Linux2/x86_64/gcc/4.8.2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/include` to avoid the error `cannot find jni.h` which I hit before including the path.

I also tried to compile using gcc, in place of g++.

Do I need to create .dll of this third-party library(currently it is archived .a containing .obj files)?

Being a newbie in cross compilers, I might be doing something wrong. Please correct me and any suggestions with this will be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -v`                                           adding this solved my problem